# Payment Failed Emails M 2.3.5 - Not working for us

Tags: magento2.2, email-templates, security, order-email

We are currently using Magento 2.3.5

From my understanding, payment failed emails are sent when a transaction fails.  By fails I hope that this means it is declined or voided by the payment method.  We need this to alert us when we are being bombarded by bots checking stolen credit card numbers.

I set this up in the backend. I made sure that the "**Email Sender**" and the "**Email Receiver**" were valid.  I also added a "**Send Payment Failed email copy to**" to another email ( also valid).

I then placed a transaction with a credit card that was not valid and with a CVV that was incorrect.  The payment gateway declined the transaction and on the checkout page I saw a red highlighted message that it failed.  No emails were sent.

Do I have it configured incorrectly?
Does it not trigger on declined transactions?  If not, is there a way to get an email when a transaction is declined ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

After entering the wrong info, did it redirect you to another page or it just show the error immediately?

If the error is shown immediately, it's client side or javascript validate, so there will be NO email for it

Comment: It did not redirect me to another page.  It stayed on the Checkout.  However the transaction was sent to the Gateway.  I looked at our Gateway's backend and I see the transaction with a declined status.    The current reason that I am looking into this is because we are experiencing attacks from bot placing multiple orders with bad CC info.  We are charged for the transactions.  Is there some way to force the condition when the payement method declines the transaction.  That way we would at least me notified that we are under attack.

Comment: I contacted the developers of the payment method extensions about this.  Apparently they did not implement the part for the Failed Transaction Email.  They did not think that it was important.  Is there a way to force the condition when the payment method declines the transaction ?